# Can you use a parameter to reference a column in a select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, parameters, where-clause

I am trying to reference a table column based on a parameter.  The last line of my where clause is

```
'GRAD_' +LEFT(@REPORTING_DATE-20000,4) LIKE '%' + @PROGRAM + '%'
```

I hoping to get my the code to look like `GRAD_2018 LIKE '%BIOL%'` but when I run the code I get a '0' in the result set where I know I should be getting 18.

Below is my sample code

```
DECLARE
@REPORTING_DATE INT,
@PROGRAM VARCHAR(4)

SET @REPORTING_DATE = '20201101'
SET @PROGRAM = 'BIOL'

SELECT COUNT(ID) 
FROM PROGRAM_DATA
WHERE PROGRAM LIKE '%' + @PROGRAM + '%' AND REPORT_DATE IN (@REPORTING_DATE-60000) AND
 'GRAD_' +LEFT(@REPORTING_DATE-20000,4) LIKE '%' + @PROGRAM + '%'
```

I am using MSSQL and SSRS.

Comment: The need to do this suggests a flaw in your data model.  You are storing values in columns that should be in separate rows.

Comment: Are you not also trying to treat @PROGRAM as a column? If not, then `@PROGRAM LIKE '%' + @PROGRAM + '%'` is pointless since (replacing variables with literals) 'BIOL' is always like '%BIOL%'. Your use of `IN` is also misleading to the reader since you filter for one specific value - that can easily be replaced with an equality (REPORT_DATE = ...)

Comment: The data table I have is not in the right format to do what I am asking so I have modified it to be able to run a proper script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't reference fields like that. You would need to use dynamic SQL to do this.

You build the SQL as a string and then EXECUTE it.

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(8000)

SET @SQL ='
SELECT COUNT(ID) 
FROM PROGRAM_DATA
WHERE @PROGRAM LIKE ''%' + @PROGRAM + '%'' 
    AND REPORT_DATE IN (''' + @REPORTING_DATE-60000 + ''') 
    AND GRAD_' + LEFT(@REPORTING_DATE-20000,4) + ' LIKE ''%''' + @PROGRAM + '''%''
    '

EXEC(@SQL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this in SSRS is by creating your dataset from an expression.

In this example, I've assumed you actually want to pass the variable values from report parameters.

Create parameters to hold you two variables, called `pReportDate` and `pProgram`.

In the dataset properties, click the expression button against the query `[fx]` .

Make sure you include the equal sign and set the whole sql statement in quotes something like.

```
="
SELECT COUNT(ID) 
FROM PROGRAM_DATA
WHERE PROGRAM LIKE '%" & Parameters!pProgram.Value & "%' AND REPORT_DATE IN (" & Parameters!pReportDate.Value & "-60000) AND
 'GRAD_' +LEFT(&" Parameters!pReportDate.Value &"-20000,4) LIKE '%" & Parameters!pProgram.Value & "%'"
```

I've also assumed that @PROGRAM was a typo in the first part of your where clause.

The drawback with this approach is the you will probably have to manually add all the query fields to the dataset as SSRS may not be able to detect them automatically.

Answer (score 0):

One more thought... since a table generally has a fixed number of columns, have you considered writing your where clause to simply spell out all of the columns with 'and' or 'or' as applies to your case?